# Techniques for addressing the homoskedasticity and normality assumption violations in mixed models with a non-all-positive response variable

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I have a mixed model which the heteroskedasticity and normality assumptions for the residuals are violated.  Up to this point, I have been addressing that by using the `robustlmm` package in R. My dependent variable is a contrast which can vary around 0; I can't log transform it. (Even before it becomes a contrast it can vary around 0.)

I understand there is a [version of the Box Cox transformation](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/normal-distributions/box-cox-transformation/) that works for data with negative values, but the `boxcox` function in the MASS package only accepts positive response variables and I have no idea how I would go about identifying two lambdas, or whether this is something I should be investigating at all.

I am wondering whether there is something further I can or should do. For more information about my data, I have two categorical predictor variables (TargetType and Taught) and one continuous predictor (Accuracy) that in its untransformed state could vary between -5 and 5. It is a subtraction/contrast of a response variable that could vary from 1-6 between a two levels of a third variable (Relevance) in the experiment.

My response variable is a subtraction in brain data between the two levels of Relevance.  I have been normalizing both of these contrast variables.

My model: RelevanceContrast_brain ~ TargetType * Taught * RelevanceContrast_accuracy + (1|subject/run) + (1|subject:cluster)

Here are the plots rlmer is generating.  On one hand those residuals, especially at the right hand of the fitted values versus residuals plot, are extreme, as is the heteroskedasticity.  On the other hand, they're being downweighted by the robust regression.  I just don't know whether I need to or should do anything else.

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:  In response to comments, I tried a cube root transform of the response variable.  This created a bimodal distribution and, seemingly as a result, created a weird pattern in the residuals.

Old distribution (this is now not the normalized response variable -- it's the original contrast):
[image]

New distribution:
[image]

Weird residuals:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it would solve your problems, but a cube-root transformation has some of the nice properties of a log transformation ('pulls in' the extreme values) while also working on zeroes and negative values.

Comment: @mkt thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: If there is a natural (negative) minimum of your scale, you can add that and then do any transformation for positive values.  Other than that, your plots don't look that bad to me. There is an outlier, but also a healthily large sample size, so the outlier may not have that much influence (you can compare a fit with and without to see it), and in any case the robust method should deal with it just fine. Your heteroscedasticity is for sure not "extreme". I probably wouldn't worry much about it.

Comment: A general thing to understand about model assumptions is that "all models are wrong", so model assumptions are pretty much always violated. It is not important to fulfill model assumptions (this is impossible anyway), but rather whether existing violations of the model assumptions have the potential to mislead the conclusions. This is admittedly often hard to know, however I suspect in your case the violations may not make much of a difference.

Comment: There's no natural minimum in the response variable.   Also, I tried the cube root transformation and it caused problems -- it made my variable bimodal for some reason, and induced some weird pattern in the residuals as a result of the bimodality.  It wasn't a clear improvement.  Maybe I will just have to accept my residuals as they are and be satisfied with robust regression as a way to address them.

Comment: Bimodality in the predictor or response is not a problem, and changing the distribution is part of the point of a transformation. If you add plots about the 'weird pattern in the residuals', you may get feedback here about what the best course of action is.

Comment: @mkt ok, done! Thanks for your engagement.

Comment: Consider a semiparametric model (see an intro to the topic [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo)).   But you may have a more basic problem.  Any time you subject one measurement from another you are assuming the measurements to be perfectly transformed.  It would be nice if there is a way to analyze the more raw form of the data.  If there is no way to do that and still answer your question of interest, think hard about hidden assumptions in any normalizations you are computing.  Typically hidden assumptions are linearity and normality, another reason to try to stick to raw data.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Ok, I'll read about semiparametric models, thanks.  If by "raw form of the data" you mean to question whether I have to normalize my variables, no, I don't, and in fact I was considering cutting that out because I think in some ways it's less interpretable.  If you mean do I have to subtract to get a contrast, the reason I need to do that is to avoid a four-way interaction.  My effects are already really complicated, as was the experimental paradigm, and I'm trying to choose analyses that are more easily interpretable.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I am working on understanding semi parametric models, but in the meantime, do I have it right that your package, `rms` doesn't support mixed models, and the `ordinal` package supports mixed models but not continuous response variables?  That is going to make this a hard circle to square.

Comment: For random effects in ordinal models you can use the frequentist packages `ordinal` and `mixor` or the Bayesian package `rmsb`.  For the latter see https://hbiostat.org/R/rmsb

Comment: Those are indeed strange residual plots. I'm not too familiar with interpreting residual plots from mixed models, but do you have 2 (unmodelled) categories in your data, by any chance? That could explain the two clouds of points in the transformed fitted vs. residuals plot.

Comment: @mkt I mean, stimuli were valence-balanced, but by the time of this analysis valence has been averaged over, so, no, not really.  The two clouds only emerge on taking the cube root.  I don't know what to make of that.  

Meanwhile, it doesn't seem like there's a way to try a semi-parametric model in R with a mixed model and a continuous response variable.  Oh, but it just occurred to me that my accuracy variable could quite reasonably be treated as ordinal.  If I flipped which variable I'm calling independent and which is dependent I could then try a semi-parametric regression.

Comment: Choosing which is dependent and which is independent is not a trivial decision and should in most cases be based on causal reasoning - so flipping them would be an unusual choice. I'm still surprised by the bimodality. Last question on this topic - are you sure it (bimodality) does not appear in the *untransformed* data as well if you choose narrower bins? Right now it could be being suppressed by the bin width.

Comment: You're right -- I just remembered why I didn't flip them.  The truth is, I don't like my current set up in terms of interpretation -- that's why I was so casual about flipping them. I would love to.  But I only have one behavioral measure for all the clusters, but I have an individual brain measurement for each cluster.  It seemed intuitively wrong to me to have many lines in a dataset predicting the same measurement which was taken once. On the other hand, it did not seem wrong to have the same predictor reused for a genuinely separate brain measurement.  Ok, I'm back to being out of ideas.

Comment: I will adjust the bin width and let you know!

Comment: Nope, I just put in 100 bins.  It is a very well-behaved looking distribution with a single mode.